# How to load external templates via Marionette.TemplateCache

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I want to load external templates using Marionette.TemplateCache and compile them after loading. As documentation say I overwrite loadTemplate and compileTemplate

```
Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.loadTemplate = function (templateId, options) {

    var 
    template    = '',
    tmplName    = templateId.replace('#', '');

    $.ajax({

        url:        '/assets/templates/' + tmplName + '.html',
        success:    function (templateHtml) {
            return templateHtml;
        }
    });
}

Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.compileTemplate = function (rawTemplate, options) {

    return _.template(rawTemplate, options);
}
```

But script not working as I want (because ajax request is async). I don't want to use async: false in ajax request because it is deprecated.

How can I solve a problem? Thanks in advance!